# FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number

Tags: http, flutter, radix

I'm trying to receive a get request using Flutter and HttpClient.

This is complete code in what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
  getSuggest() async {
    try {
      var httpClient = new HttpClient();
      var uri = new Uri.http(
          'http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com', '/6.2/suggest.json', {
        'app_id': 'APP_ID',
        'app_code': 'APP_CODE',
        'query': '123 Main Street',
        'country': 'USA',
        'language': 'en',
      });
      var request = await httpClient.getUrl(uri);
      var response = await request.close();
      var responseBody = await response.transform(Utf8Decoder()).join();
      Map data = jsonDecode(responseBody);
      print(data);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

And I'm using

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
```

But my code always gets sent to the `print(error)` and the error that gets printed is

> FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post the whole error log ?

Comment: Print `response.body` and post the output

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is the scheme. You don't have to set it in `Uri.http` or `Uri.https` methods, it is set automatically, so change with the following:

```
Uri.http(
        'autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com', '/6.2/suggest.json', {
        'app_id': 'APP_ID',
        'app_code': 'APP_CODE',
        'query': '123 Main Street',
        'country': 'USA',
        'language': 'en',
      });
```

And I suggest using [http](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) package and do something like that:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


final json = const JsonCodec();
getSuggest() async {
    try {
      var uri = Uri.http(
          'autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com', '/6.2/suggest.json', {
        'app_id': 'APP_ID',
        'app_code': 'APP_CODE',
        'query': '123 Main Street',
        'country': 'USA',
        'language': 'en',
      });
      var response = await http.get(uri);
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      print(data);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

and use its `http client` if you need to set much more things (e.g. `User Agents`).

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 4):

```
var url = Uri.https('http://192.168.43.5:3000/api', '/auth/getAllUsers', {'q': '{http}'});
```

The reason of this error is you do not have to provide https:// like above. Base url is enough. Additionally, you should use `Uri.http` instead of `Uri.https`, since your URL uses `http://` (not `https://`). You should do it like the following.

```
var url = Uri.http('192.168.43.5:3000/api', '/auth/getAllUsers', {'q': '{http}'});
```