# Flutter uses http to retrieve the background interface, error: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number

Tags: flutter

Use http to get background data in flutter, but the debug console reports FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number. Why?

The library has been introduced and is the latest version
I thought it was the wrong interface. Now I changed it to the correct one that I can access.

```
_get() async{
    print(3);
    try {
      var uri =  Uri.http('https://short-msg-ms.juejin.im/v1/topicList/recommend?uid=&device_id=&token=&src=web','');
      var response = await http.get(uri);
      print(response);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

Error result：

I/flutter ( 3573): FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956571/formatexception-invalid-radix-10-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Uri.http()` in a wrong way. Please read: [doc](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html)

Example:

```
// http://example.org/path?q=dart.
new Uri.http("example.org", "/path", { "q" : "dart" });
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try `dio` to get it.

--

First import dio

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
```

and add it in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  dio: ^1.0.13
```

and try this:

```
_get() async{
    Dio dio = new Dio();
　　Response response;

    try {
      response = await dio.get(
      "https://short-msg-ms.juejin.im/v1/topicList/recommend?uid=&device_id=&token=&src=web");
      print(response);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```