# Trying to obtain data from API - Invalid radix-10 number

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to learn Flutter/Dart and I'm having to much problems. Now I'm trying to obtain some values from an API. My code is:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:myapp01_apirequest/src/models/uplink_models.dart';

class UplinksProvider{
  String _url       = 'https://xxx.yyy.com:14442/api/external/';

  Future<List<Uplink>> getEnCines() async{
    try{
      final url = Uri.https(_url, 'login', {
        'username': 'Joe689',
        'password': '15.Job_1825zz'
      });

      final resp = await http.get(url);
      final decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);
      print('Patata');
      print(decodedData);
      
      return [];
    }catch (error){
      print('++++++++++///////++++++++++++++++');
      print(error);
      print('++++++++++*******++++++++++++++++');
    }
  }
}
```

With the `try/catch` I obtain this error:

```
I/flutter ( 3714): ++++++++++///////++++++++++++++++
I/flutter ( 3714): FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
I/flutter ( 3714): //xxx.yyy.com:14442/api/external/
I/flutter ( 3714): ^
I/flutter ( 3714): ++++++++++*******++++++++++++++++
```

I found a lot of posts asking the same, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956571/formatexception-invalid-radix-10-number) one, but I'm not sure to understand it.

My idea is that I'm receiving a bad response, with a bad encoding, but I don't know how to solve it.

Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What structure do you have in Uplink model?

Comment: Which _specific_ line of code is throwing this error? (Get the stacktrace data in the catch block by changing the parentheses to `catch (error, stacktrace)`.)

Comment: Please update your question with only whatever changes you have made and whatever errors you have faced. Or create a new question for the same.

Comment: @PreetShah YES! I did a new post, sorry!

Comment: No need to apologize. Just letting you know that you should create new questions for new errors. So that, people can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `https://` from your URL.

See [the docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html). You aren't supposed to include the scheme. That's why you call `Uri.https`.